# Matplotlib set_yticklabels from several np.array()

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have two `numpy` arrays, `prot_name` and `prot_nHarea`, which are used to label yticks

```
prot_name = np.array(['HEMO', 'HSA', 'EGF', 'MYO', 'LACT', 'CKMM', 'BMG', 'IGF', 'CYTC', 'IFN', 'CREA', 'IL8'])
```

`prot_nHarea` has 12 matrices for each `prot_name`.

I want to have the first line of each y tick as `prot_name` followed by `np.sum()` of its matrix in `prot_nHarea`. The next line has its `np.mean()` of `prot_nHarea`.

[image]

Now I am doing hard code to label y ticks. But is there any ways to iterate through `np.array(prot_name)` followed by `np.sum(np.array(prot_nHarea))` and `np.mean(np.array(prot_nHarea))`? The value from sum and mean are written in scientific pattern and I adjust the label a bit by `\n` when they are overlapped.

```
    ax0.set_yticklabels(["K1 - HEMO sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[0])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[0]))), 
                    "K2 - HSA sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[1])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[1])))+"\n", 
                    "\nK3 - EGF sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[2])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[2]))),
                    "K4 - MYO sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[3])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[3]))),
                    "K5 - LACT sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[4])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[4]))),
                    "K6 - CKMM sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[5])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[5]))),
                    "K7 - BMG sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[6])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[6])))+"\n",
                    "K8 - IGF sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[7])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[7]))),
                    "K9 - CYTC sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[8])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[8]))),
                    "K10 - IFN sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[9])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[9]))),
                    "K11 - CREA sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[10])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[10]))),
                    "K12 - IL8 sum: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.sum(prot_nHarea[11])))+"\nmean: "+str('{:.2e}'.format(np.mean(prot_nHarea[11])))], fontsize='x-small')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension, making use of `zip` and `enumerate` to loop through `prot_name` and `prot_nHarea` at the same time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prot_name = np.array([
    'HEMO', 'HSA', 'EGF', 'MYO',
    'LACT', 'CKMM', 'BMG', 'IGF',
    'CYTC', 'IFN', 'CREA', 'IL8'
    ])
prot_nHarea = np.random.rand(12, 100)

yticklabels = ['K{} - {} sum: {:.2e} \nmean: {:.2e}'.format(
    i, name, Harea.sum(), Harea.mean()
    ) for i, (name, Harea) in enumerate(zip(prot_name, prot_nHarea))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_yticks(range(12))
ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It works so well. Thanks so much. May I ask if I want to add `\n` at the end of every label but the number of `\n` is not equal between labels. Like I set array of number of newline called `interval`, then # `yticklabels = ['K{} - {} sum: {:.2e} \nmean: {:.2e} \n*interval'.format(
    i, name, Harea.sum(), Harea.mean()
    ) for i, (name, Harea) in enumerate(zip(prot_name, prot_nHarea))]` The purpose is I want to set the label at the center of its group between ticks (but my each K has different number of rows so I can't fix number). Where should I insert `\n*interval` here?